# Multtest package in R returning not properly adjusting p-values

Tags: r, vector, false-positive

I am trying to use the R package multtest to adjust a list of p-values for multiple testing. However, multtest will only return a list of "1" characters of equal length to the list of p-values that were analyzed.

The input file is a text file in which the pvalues are separated by newline characters. A segment of the file is reproduced below:

```
0.182942602
0.333002877
0.282000206
0.161501682
0.161501682
```

I downloaded the multtest package (multtest_2.14.0) from Bioconductor, and am running it in R version x64 2.15.2. Does anyone know if there is a compatibility problem between multtest and R 2.15.2?

My code:

```
library(multtest, verbose = FALSE)
table1 <- read.table("p-values.txt", header = FALSE, colClasses = "double")
table2 <-as.vector(as.double(table1[,1]))
results<-p.adjust(table2, method = c("holm", "hochberg", "hommel", "bonferroni", "BH", "BY", "fdr", "none"))
write.table(results, file = "output.txt")
```

Comment: Are you sure that a vector of 1s is not the correct adjustment? How long is your input vector of p-values, and what is the smallest one? (If the smallest value is larger than `1/n`, where `n` is the number of p-values, then a Bonferroni correction would indeed lead to a vector of 1s)

Comment: (Also, why are you passing it multiple methods? It only takes one argument of a method, so in this case it would use the first one, Holm).

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error- this is the correct adjustment when there are no p-values that can be considered significant within that vector of p-values.

Your code performs the Holm correction (`method` takes only one argument, and in this case will use the `"holm"` method, the first item in your vector). The Holm method will correctly return all ones in the case that

```
min(p) * length(p) > 1
```

In that situation (using this multiple hypothesis testing framework), there are no p-values in the vector that can be considered significant.

---

If you'd like to see the gory details, the code for the `holm` method (taken directly from the multtest package) is

```
i <- seq_len(lp)
o <- order(p)
ro <- order(o)
pmin(1, cummax((n - i + 1L) * p[o]))[ro]
```

where `p` is the input vector, and `lp` and `n` are the length of the vector. That expression `(n - i + 1L) * p[o]` is saying "for each item in the sorted list, take `n+1` minus its index, then multiply it by the value". For the minimum item, that is `(n + 1 - 1) * min(p)` -> `n * min(p)`. The `cummax` means the cumulative maximum- which means that none of the subsequent items can be smaller than the first value. And `pmin(1, ...)` means that for every item in the vector, if the item is greater than 1, set the value equal to 1 (since a p-value about 1 is meaningless).

This means that if `n * min(p)` is greater than one, then the adjusted p-value of the smallest item is 1, which means the adjusted p-value of every item must be 1.